# Create a python dictionary with unique keys that have list as their values

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary as following -

```
{'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b':[1, 3, 5], 'c':[2, 3, 5]}
```

The way I have implemented it is

```
mydict = dict()
letters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'] 

#please mark the list has multiple occurence of a, 
#hence I would want to check if a key with 'a' exists. Please do not advise to make the list unique. 
for l in letters:
    if not mydict.get(l):
        mydict[l] =  <values from another place via some filter>
    else:
        mydict[l].append(<values from another dict>)
```

Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: I'll get the "have you tried" `mydict = {'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b':[1, 3, 5], 'c':[2, 3, 5]}` out of the way... Umm, what's the pattern used to generate this, how is `letters` related etc... There's not info. here to help you... What is values from another dict, what is value from another place etc... etc...

Comment: What are you expecting your output to look like?

Comment: Use `key in mydict` to check if a key is in a dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

Sample code:

```
»»» from collections import defaultdict

»»» mydict = defaultdict(list)

»»» letters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'] 

»»» for l in letters:
   ....:     mydict[l].append('1')
   ....:     

»»» mydict
Out[15]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['1', '1', '1'], 'c': ['1'], 'b': ['1']})
```

If you need the content to be initialised to something fancier, you can specify your own construction function as the first argument to `defaultdict`. Passing context-specific arguments to that constructor might be tricky though.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by m01 is cool and all but I believe it's worth mentionning that we can do that with a plain dict object..

```
mydict = dict()
letters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a']

for l in letters:
    mydict.setdefault(l, []).append('1')
```

the result should be the same. You'll have a default dict instead of using a subclass. It really depends on what you're looking for. My guess is that the big problem with my solution is that it will create a new list even if it is not needed.

The `defaultdict` object has the advantage to create a new object only when something is missing. This solution has the advantage to be a simple dict without nothing special.

**Edit**

After thinking about it, I found out that using `setdefault` on a `defaultdict` will work as expected. But it's not yet good enough to say that a plain old `dict` should be used instead. There are cases where having a `dict` is important. To make it short, an invalid key on a `dict` will raise a `KeyError`. A `defaultdict` will return a default value.

As an example, there is the traversal algorithm that stops whenever it catches a KeyError or it traversed a whole path. With a `defaultdict`, you'd have to raise yourself the KeyError in case of errors.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this was possible. However, is there much of an advantage in using a plain `dict` over a `defaultdict`, given Python's duck typing? You can also always construct a plain dict from the data in the `defaultdict`, too, using `dict(mydict)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict`. (See [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples))

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
letters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'] 

for l in letters:
    mydict[l].append(<some data>)
```